# Update combobox while using DisplayMemberPath

Tags: wpf, combobox, mvvm-light

I am using WPF and MVVM light framework (and I am new in using them)

Here is the situation:

- I have a combobox displaying a list of items (loaded from a database) and I am using the DisplayMemberPath to display the title of the items in the combobox.
- In the same GUI, the user can modify the item title in a text box. A button 'Save' allows the user to save the data into the database.

What I want to do is when the user clicks 'Save', the item title in the combobox gets updated too and the new value is displayed at that time. However, I do not know how to do that...

Some details on my implementation:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SourceData}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSourceData,Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Title" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedDataInTextFormat}"/>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Closing += (s, e) => ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.xaml

```
public class MainViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
  public ObservableCollection<Foo> SourceData{get;set;}
  public Foo SelectedSourceData 
  { 
    get{return _selectedFoo;}
    set{_selectedFoo=value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedSourceData"); }
  }

  public string SelectedDataInTextFormat
  {
    get{return _selectedDataInTextFormat;}
    set{_selectedDataInTextFormat=value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDataInTextFormat");
  }
}
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me on this one.

Thanks for your help.

Romain

Comment: Have you tried rebinding the control by resetting `myComboBox.ItemsSource = SourceData;` after the `SourceData` collection has been updated?

Comment: If I specify the combobox name in MainWindow.xaml, how can I access it in MainViewModel.cs?

Comment: If you name it `name="myComboBox"` in the xaml, then just use `myComboBox` in the .cs code

Comment: Hi Paul. I updated my question. Your answer is correct if the code is located in MainWindow.xaml.cs . However, I do not have access to the combobox in MainViewModel.cs which is currently what I am trying to do.

Comment: But surely your MainViewWindow must have a reference to the MainViewModel?

Comment: Hi Romain, why not just set `SelectedDataInTextformat` to your `SelectedSourceData.Title`? Then `RaisePropertyChanged` on your `SelectedSourceData`? That way your textbox is binding indirectly to your `ComboBox` `SelectedItem`.

Comment: @Bob: it is working half-way...let me explain. let's say I select "Title 1" in the combobox and then I update it to "bla bla" in the textbox and I click 'Save', at this point I will trigger the RaisePropertyChanged on SelectedSourceData. However, it does not display the updated value in the combobox immediatly. When I click on the combobox, I can still see "Title 1" but, when I select "Title 1", it will display "bla bla". It seems that the combobox displays the original values when you click on the combobox but displays the correct values upon selection. It is really confusing.

Comment: @paul: no i do not have. this MainWindow is tight up with a ViewModelLocator (default template from MVVM light framework).

Comment: Is your `UpdateSourceTrigger` set to `PropertyChanged`?

Comment: @Bob: I did not set any UpdateSourceTrigger in the MainWindow.xaml for the combobox: <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SourceData}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSourceData,Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Title" />

Comment: solution from Clemens below works just fine. Thanks again for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might simply update the `SelectedSourceData` property when `SelectedDataInTextFormat` changes:

```
public string SelectedDataInTextFormat
{
    get { return _selectedDataInTextFormat; }
    set
    {
        _selectedDataInTextFormat = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDataInTextFormat");

        SelectedSourceData = SourceData.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Title == _selectedDataInTextFormat)
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: In order to change the `Title` property of the currently selected `Foo` item in the ComboBox, you could implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms133020.aspx) in your Foo class:

```
public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string title = string.Empty;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set
        {
            title = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Title"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then simply set the `Title` property of the selected item:

```
SelectedSourceData.Title = SelectedDataInTextFormat;
```

Comment: Hi Clemens. There is no FirstOrDefault method in ObservableCollection

Comment: Sorry, it's an extension method in [System.Linq.Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Linq.Enumerable.aspx). You have to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Thanks. However, this will not work as the title in the text box is filled-up by the user, it is not part of the initial values contained in the combobox. As a result, the FirstOrDefault will return null (I just tested it right now).

Comment: Then why not simply create a new item, add it to `SourceData`, and then set it as `SelectedItem`?

Comment: I do not want to add a new item in the SourceData. I would like to update it. As I explained previously, it seems that the update is fine, but when you select the combobox, it displays the old values...However, if I select an item in the combobox, then it will display the correct value.

Comment: Ok, so you want to change the `Title` property of the `SelectedSourceData` object? See my edit. Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` is the usual way to notify about property changes.

Comment: it works! :-) Thank you so much, I was really struggling with this one.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to do this, This example takes advantage of the `Button` `Tag` property to send some data to the save button handler(or `ICommand`), Then we can set the `TextBox` `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `Explicit` and call the update when the `Button` is clicked.

Example:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="105" Width="156" Name="UI">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <StackPanel Name="stackPanel1">
            <ComboBox x:Name="combo" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceData}" DisplayMemberPath="Title" SelectedIndex="0"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtbox" Text="{Binding ElementName=combo, Path=SelectedItem.Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
            <Button Content="Save" Tag="{Binding ElementName=txtbox}" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Foo> _sourceData = new ObservableCollection<Foo>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SourceData.Add(new Foo { Title = "Stack" });
        SourceData.Add(new Foo { Title = "Overflow" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Foo> SourceData
    {
        get { return _sourceData; }
        set { _sourceData = value; }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var txtbx = (sender as Button).Tag as TextBox;
        txtbx.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}


public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Title"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand the principle but all your code would be located in MainWindow.xaml.cs but my code is located in MainViewModel.cs . So how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
public ObservableCollection<Foo> SourceData{get;set;}
public Foo SelectedSourceData 
{
    get{
        return _selectedFoo;
    }
    set{
        _selectedFoo=value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedSourceData");
    }
}

public string SelectedDataInTextFormat //Bind the text to the SelectedItem title
{
    get{
        return SelectedSourceData.Title
    }
    set{
        SelectedSourceData.Title=value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDataInTextFormat");
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SourceData, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSourceData,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Title" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedDataInTextFormat, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```